# How To Hide Schema from user

Tags: schema, users

I have DB with 2 schemas: A and B.  B schema's procedures use A schema's procedures.

I need to create user, which will not be able to see A schema. This user can use only B schema, but i want to let the user execute B's procedures that use A's procedures...

Answer (score 1):

The basic concept is to use [GRANT/DENY Schema Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). You can efficiently manage permissions by creating a role and then adding members to it.

Below is an example that will explain you in detail

```
use master
go
--Create Logins
CREATE LOGIN UserA WITH Password='UserA123';
go
CREATE LOGIN UserB WITH Password='UserB123';

use AdventureWorks2008R2
go
--Create Database Users
CREATE USER UserA;
go
CREATE USER UserB;
go
--Create the Test Schemas
CREATE SCHEMA SchemaA AUTHORIZATION UserA
go
CREATE SCHEMA SchemaB AUTHORIZATION UserB
go

-- create test tables
create table schemaA.TableA (fname char(5))
go
insert into schemaA.TableA (fname) values ('Kin-A')
go

create table SchemaB.TableB (fname char(5))
go
insert into SchemaB.TableB (fname) values ('Kin-B')
go
```

Now test :

```
--Test for UserA in SchemaA
EXEC('select * from schemaA.TableA') AS USER = 'UserA'
go
--Kin-A

-- Test for UserB in SchemaB == this should fail
EXEC('select * from SchemaB.TableB') AS USER = 'UserA'
go
--Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
--The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TableB', database 'AdventureWorks2008R2', schema 'SchemaB'.
```

Now create Stored Procedures :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SchemaB.proc_SelectUserB
AS
    select * from schemaA.TableA;
go
create procedure schemaA.proc_SchemaA
as 
    select * from schemaA.TableA
```

Now Grant execute permissions to UserA on schemaB's SP

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[SchemaB].[proc_SelectUserB] TO [UserA] 
go
```

Test it .. to see if UserA is able to run SP from schemaB. This will PASS

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='UserA';
    Exec SchemaB.proc_SelectUserB;
    revert;
go
--- Kin-A
```

But UserA wont be able to see data from SchemaB

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='UserA';
    select * from SchemaB.TableB
revert;
go

--- Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 3
--- The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TableB', database 'AdventureWorks2008R2', schema 'SchemaB'.
```

**Alternatively you can use DATABASE ROLE and just add users to it for better manageability of permissions:**

```
EXEC sp_addrole 'SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc'
go
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc','UserA';
go
```

Below statement will make sure that UserA is able to see schemaA and NOT schemaB. The good thing is that you can just add users to `SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc` role and they will inherit all the permissions granted to that role.

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::SchemaA TO SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc;
go
```

If you only want to allow UserA to execute SP's which are owned by SchemaB then below statement will do the job:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[SchemaB].[proc_SelectUserB] TO [SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc] 
go
```

This way, UserA is not able to see SchemaB's tables, but still can execute procs from SchemaB.

Below will explain the [permission hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191465%28SQL.90%29.aspx) :

[image]