# Setting user permissions for different SQL Server schemas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to limit access to a particular user, but they still need to be able to see the data in tables owned by dbo.

I'm trying to do the following:

1. dbo schema functions as it would normally, has access to everything
2. schema1 schema has access to only schema1 objects
3. if a schema1 view or stored procedure accesses data in tables owned by dbo, the permissions chain appropriately
4. user1 has access to schema1, and nothing else; except in the case of #3

Here's what I've tried:

1. Create a user1 user mapped to a test login with a random password
2. Created a couple tables in the dbo schema with some test data in them
3. Created a schema1 schema
4. Created a schema1.get_profiles that selects from a view called schema1.profiles which accesses data in dbo.people, dbo.taglinks, and dbo.tags

However, using the following statement while logged in as user1:

```
EXEC get_profiles 1
```

results in:

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tags', database 'schema_test', schema 'dbo'.
```

I have tried `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` and can't begin to understand how "ownership chaining" is supposed to work.

I have also tried

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::schema1 TO user1
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::schema1 TO user1
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::schema1 TO user1
GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::schema1 TO user1
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::schema1 TO user1
```

but I get the following error (despite being a user with dbo-level access):

```
Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
```

What I need is user1 to be able to access the data via the stored procedures I give it, and nothing else.

Additionally, this is intended to eventually live on an existing SQL Azure database, but I'm testing against a local dummy database first.

Comment: Refer to my answer : [How To Hide Schema from user](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53419/8783) Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: This seems to made it more clear to me. I think the problem was I had the owner of Schema1 set to User1, instead of dbo. I set Schema1 to be owned by User1, adapted and followed the question, and I was able to get something working. You may propose an answer to the question if you want. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The basic concept is to use [GRANT/DENY Schema Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). You can efficiently manage permissions by creating a role and then adding members to it.

Below is an example that will explain you in detail

```
use master
go
--Create Logins
CREATE LOGIN UserA WITH Password='UserA123';
go
CREATE LOGIN UserB WITH Password='UserB123';

use AdventureWorks2008R2
go
--Create Database Users
CREATE USER UserA;
go
CREATE USER UserB;
go
--Create the Test Schemas
CREATE SCHEMA SchemaA AUTHORIZATION UserA
go
CREATE SCHEMA SchemaB AUTHORIZATION UserB
go

-- create test tables
create table schemaA.TableA (fname char(5))
go
insert into schemaA.TableA (fname) values ('Kin-A')
go

create table SchemaB.TableB (fname char(5))
go
insert into SchemaB.TableB (fname) values ('Kin-B')
go
```

Now test :

```
--Test for UserA in SchemaA
EXEC('select * from schemaA.TableA') AS USER = 'UserA'
go
--Kin-A

-- Test for UserB in SchemaB == this should fail
EXEC('select * from SchemaB.TableB') AS USER = 'UserA'
go
--Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
--The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TableB', database 'AdventureWorks2008R2', schema 'SchemaB'.
```

Now create Stored Procedures :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SchemaB.proc_SelectUserB
AS
    select * from schemaA.TableA;
go
create procedure schemaA.proc_SchemaA
as 
    select * from schemaA.TableA
```

Now Grant execute permissions to UserA on schemaB's SP

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[SchemaB].[proc_SelectUserB] TO [UserA] 
go
```

Test it .. to see if UserA is able to run SP from schemaB. This will PASS

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='UserA';
    Exec SchemaB.proc_SelectUserB;
    revert;
go
--- Kin-A
```

But UserA wont be able to see data from SchemaB

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='UserA';
    select * from SchemaB.TableB
revert;
go

--- Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 3
--- The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TableB', database 'AdventureWorks2008R2', schema 'SchemaB'.
```

**Alternatively you can use DATABASE ROLE and just add users to it for better manageability of permissions:**

```
EXEC sp_addrole 'SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc'
go
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc','UserA';
go
```

Below statement will make sure that UserA is able to see schemaA and NOT schemaB. The good thing is that you can just add users to `SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc` role and they will inherit all the permissions granted to that role.

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::SchemaA TO SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc;
go
```

If you only want to allow UserA to execute SP's which are owned by SchemaB then below statement will do the job:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[SchemaB].[proc_SelectUserB] TO [SchemaBUsesSchemaAProc] 
go
```

This way, UserA is not able to see SchemaB's tables, but still can execute procs from SchemaB.

Below will explain the [permission hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191465%28SQL.90%29.aspx) :

[image]

Comment: Just to reiterate, it's important that both schemas are owned by the same user. That was the main issue I was having.