# SSMS: Limit a login to be able to view and work only with some databases, but not able to make any changes on the server level

Tags: sql-server, ssms, permissions

On a shared cloud we would like to work with one instance of MS SQL Server. Different clients have various databases. They can be owner of their databases and with DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO PUBLIC in SSMS they can only see their databases. That works fine. To connect to SSMS they need the CONTROL SERVER permission. But even after a DENY of all the server level permissions they are able to do many things in SSMS, like restart the sql server services. Of course this should not be possible for such users. 
How can a user be configured not to be able to do any actions to the server itself?

Comment: `CONTROL SERVER` is an administrative permission, you don't need that to connect with SSMS. Any user that can connect to the server can also connect using SSMS, although certain administrative features and tasks will be limited by permissions, obviously.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/setting-user-permissions-for-different-sql-server-schemas

Comment: The problem is that such a user can do too much, fe restart the sql server services. How can this be prevented?

Comment: @Reto - as Daniel mentioned, the user does NOT need CONTROL SERVER to connect using SSMS.  Remove that right from the account  and the user won't be able to control the server.

Comment: @Max: adding a login to ssms without any further grants or denies or adding roles gives this user the ability to restart the services from within ssms. seems any user with role public can do that.

Comment: @Reto Some of those right-click options are checked at the Windows /  service level, not the connection level. Try some of the other things in Object Explorer, like looking at the SQL Server logs - something that *is* checked through the SQL account.

Answer (score 2):

> To connect to SSMS they need the CONTROL SERVER permission.

No, that is not true at all. I hope you didn't learn that from any documentation, blog post or presentation. If you did, you should tell us where, so we can hunt them down and correct it.

In order to connect, they need to be a member of the public role (granted by default to all logins). To do anything aside from connect, they need to be granted explicit permissions or added to server-level roles. To connect to a database, they need `CONNECT`. To do anything aside from connect to a database, they need to be granted explicit permissions or added to database roles.

If you don't want them to have the permissions inherited from `CONTROL SERVER`, then don't grant that permission. Simple.

And don't test what an end user can do *at the service level* by connecting to the server in *your* copy of Management Studio using *their* credentials. The ability to perform certain operations (like restarting the service) has nothing to do with accounts or permissions inside SQL Server - *your* Windows domain account is checked, regardless of what user is connected in Object Explorer. To verify this, go to someone's workstation who *doesn't* have the ability - via their Windows account - to restart services at the Windows level, and try again. Or create a guest account on your own machine.

Comment: I just added a new login, no further grants or denies or adding roles. a sql server user with no link to a windows user. just having role public. by now not even linked to a specific database. but he can restart the server by right-clicking on the server node.

Comment: @Reto but didn't you "need" to grant them CONTROL SERVER to connect using SSMS?

Comment: (P.S. I think that right-clicking the server node and issuing some of those commands tries to do so through the Windows login, regardless of how you connected to the SQL Server. So if *you* are "proving" this by connecting *your* Management Studio to the server, even using their credentials, and restarting the server, try having *them* actually do it. Also, try some other commands, like expanding Management > SQL Server Logs.)

Comment: no, no need to give CONTROL SERVER. that was a try by denying all the other permissions to prevent actions to the server.

Comment: @Reto and again, some of those actions have absolutely nothing to do with the SQL Server account you're connecting with. Go to the workstations of one of your peons - assuming they're not domain or local admins on the SQL Server machine, of course - and have them try to restart the server. I bet you get a different outcome than when you try it while logged in to SQL Server as them.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. that could be reason. Of course I am trying that from a domain pc that has rights also on the server...

Comment: @Reto Right. Restarting a service is a Windows-level task, not a SQL Server task, so it makes sense that doing so is checked via Windows permissions, not permissions inside the service you're trying to control. An IT admin should be able to restart SQL Server even if they don't have any access to the data inside.

Comment: @Reto AFAIK if you're attempting to interact with the SQL Server services through SSMS, you'll be connecting to the remote machine through WMI and not interacting with SQL Server AT ALL. Testing that way only verifies if your WMI security and firewalls aren't properly setup.