# How to grant insert in a table that is in another database on SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

On SQLServer 2008 R2 I have 2 schemas: DatabaseA and DatabaseB.

On DatabaseB I have a table named TableB. Whenever tableB is updated, a trigger will insert a value in the tableA (that is on DatabaseA).

For that I need to grant insert / update on tableA to UserB (that is on DatabaseB).

dbo is the owner of tables on DatabaseA and UserB is a service user of tables on DatabaseB (I mean, UserB is not the owner from tables on DatabaseB. It has limited access to them - For some tables he can insert / update permissions and for other tables it has just select permission).

After reading these articles

[GRANT Object Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Setting user permissions for different SQL Server schemas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/setting-user-permissions-for-different-sql-server-schemas)

I tried the following:

```
USE [DatabaseA]
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON DatabaseA.dbo.TableA TO [DatabaseB].[UserB]
GO
```

I got the error: 
*Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.'.*

Then I tried

```
USE [DatabaseA]
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON DatabaseA.dbo.TableA TO [UserB]
GO
```

And got message below (what makes sense taking in account UserB doesn't exist on DatabaseA):
*Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2

Cannot find the user 'UserB', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.*

Then I tried

```
USE [DatabaseA]
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON DatabaseA.dbo.TableA TO [DatabaseB\UserB]
GO
```

Which gave me
*Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot find the user 'DatabaseB\UserB', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.*

UserB does exist on DatabaseB and I'm issuing the command as sa user so I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Edited: Fixed the naming. It's database. Not schema as pointed out by [Kris Gruttemeyer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/25146/kris-gruttemeyer)

Comment: Does the user exist at the DB level.  Open your database -> Security -> Logins and make sure the user exists at the DB level, if it doesn't, you'll need to add that user to the DB so you can then grant it permissions.  Also, your use of the word 'schema' isn't correct.  In 3-part naming it's [DBNAME].[SCHEMA].[OBJECT].  In this case, your schema is dbo.

Comment: A user doesn't exist in a schema, so can you better explain what you mean by "UserB does exist on SchemaB"?

Comment: Kris / Aaron: The userB does exist in databaseB and it's able to insert / update TableB. My problem is that now I have to add a trigger that will update tableA on databaseA and I'm failing to accomplish that.

Comment: Does it exist in DatabaseA?

Comment: Kris, UserB doesn't exist on table A. Am I obligated to add it? Cannot I just grant him rights to access resources on databaseA?

Comment: You can't assign privileges to a user that doesn't exist in the target DB.  Just doesn't work that way.  All you're doing is creating the user in the target DB and then assigning it permissions, is that an issue?  Think about it, if I give one of my users read access to our Utilities DB, I don't want them, by inheritance, to have access to, say, sensitive patient data.

Comment: Okay, there is a big difference between a schema and a database in SQL Server. A schema is a container inside a database. Users are also contained inside databases. Your best bet is likely to create a user in DatabaseB that maps to the same login as that user in DatabaseA.

Comment: I see. The application (that uses UserB) just has access to Database B. Bosses won't allow me to access any other database. That's why I was trying to use a trigger between databases. Regards.

Comment: So your boss wants a particular user to access data from a database, but doesn't want to grant that user access to any of the data in that database? That does not compute for me.

Comment: Yes. I'll talk to him. Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed what I was looking for (but were unaware of its name) is called cross database ownership chaining.

By reading the article [Understanding Cross Database Ownership Chaining in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1782/understanding-cross-database-ownership-chaining-in-sql-server/)  I was able to solve my problem.

As a reference, below is what I did:

```
Use [DatabaseA]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseA]
SET DB_CHAINING ON
GO

Use [DatabaseB]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseB]
SET DB_CHAINING ON
GO

EXEC sp_grantdbaccess 'UserB';
GO 

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE on [DatabaseB].[dbo].[TableA] TO [UserB]
GO
```

Thank you all.