# Hide schemas from users in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database-design, azure-sql-database

I'm creating a database with a few different schemas.

99% of users connect using Excel, and when they do they see all the system stuff:

[image]

This just confuses the users and I would like to configure SQL Server so that they only see UK_data and UK_reports.

So far I tried denying select on the things that I want to hide and only allowing select on the UK_ schemas, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to hide them from users?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Hide Schema from user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/how-to-hide-schema-from-user)

Comment: @bbaird Thanks for your suggestion but no. That approach let's me hide the data but not the schema. I want to hide the schemas and system things to avoid confusing the users..

Comment: @Nacho so you just want to show a limited number of tables?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani something like that. I have a schema that has the tables with all the data. I created other schemas that only contain views to those tables. I want to limit which users can see which schemas, and therefore which views.

Comment: That is even better @Nacho. So users can only have access to views. Through Excel?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani exactly. The idea is that they can connect through Excel and only see the views in those schemas.

Answer (score 1):

I maybe found [two solution](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/04/03/hiding-tables-in-ssms-object-explorer-using-extended-properties/) for you:

> 1. HIDE

Hide Table "Person.Address"

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@value = 'Hide',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

Show Table "Person.Address"

```
EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

> 2. DENY

```
`DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON Schema.Table TO UserName;`
```

Now UserName won’t be abe to see Table in Object Explorer. In Fact, they won’t be able to see the table in sys.tables or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

You can Use the `DENY` keyword to deny certain Users and `REVOKE` to Remove the existing permission.